# Get components of a components object?

Tags: java, user-interface, components

Im trying to write the following just for my interest:

```
public void enableComponents(boolean enable) {
    Component[] components = getContentPane().getComponents();

    for (int i = 0; i < components.length; ++i) {
        components[i].setEnabled(enable);
    }
// [...]
```

In the "Component[]" array can e.g. also a JPanel that contains more GUI-Elements. But how could I access them? There is no method like "components[i].getCOmponents()"?

Comment: `components[i].getClass ().getName ().indexOf ("JPanel") != -1` ?

Comment: Seems like he wants to traverse that components also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The awt designer make the Container class as a special kind of Component, which I don't why either, but you can leverage this feature.

To find all subcompnents, you can check whether the component is a container. If it is not, then it cannot have subcomponents. If it is, then cast to Container and access them. Recurse if you need sub-sub-components as well.

```
Component[] components = getContentPane().getComponents();

for (int i = 0; i < components.length; ++i) {
   if ((components[i] instanceof Container)) {
       Container subContainer = (Container)components[i];
       //do something here
   }else{
       //do something here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
public void enableComponents(Container container, boolean enable) {

    Component[] components = container.getComponents();

    for (int i = 0; i < components.length; ++i) {
        components[i].setEnabled(enable);
        if (components[i] instanceof Container) {
            Container subContainer = (Container)components[i];
            enableComponents(subContainer, enable);
        }
    }
}
```

and pass in `getContentPane()` to begin.

Comment: Yep, added `Container` arg

Answer (score 0):

Components are contained by `Container`. `Panel` extends `Container`, therefore you can get its components. So, to get sub components you have to cast component to Container (if it is instance of Container):

```
public void enableComponents(boolean enable) {
    enableComponent(getContentPane());
}


public void enableComponent(Component component, boolean enable) {
    component.setEnabled(enable)

    if (component instanceof Container) {
        Container container = (Container)component;
        for (Component c : container.getComponents()) {
             enableComponent(c, enable);  // recursive call
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `enableComponent(getContentPane(), enable)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Component[] components = getContentPane().getComponents();
 for (int i = 0; i < components.length; ++i) {
    components[i].setEnabled(enable);
  }
Arrays.asList(components).get(1);
```